# Is there a way to change the current working directory within a Ballerina program?

Tags: ballerina

My requirement is to run `bal new` command within another ballerina program. This new Ballerina project needs to be created in a directory specified by the user. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `bal new` command supports creating a package in the current directory only. Therefore You can use the `os:exec()` function and pass a single bash command to change the directory to the path you want to create your project and run `bal new <packageName>`.

```
import ballerina/os;

public function main() returns error? {
    os:Command cmd = {value: "bash", arguments: ["-c", "cd dir1/dir2 && bal new foo"]};
    _ = check os:exec(cmd);
}
```